# How to write route for breadcrumb in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

```
Route::get('/usersearch', 'UsersController@usersearch');// for this url write breadcrumb
Route::Resource('user','UsersController');
```

how can i write breadcrumb route ? I want display on index.blade.php which is located in user folder

Comment: Have a look on this package: https://github.com/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs

Comment: "_how can i write breadcrumb route_" Can you explain a little more what you're trying to do? What is a "_breadcrumb route_"? Do you want to link to that route in your `index.blade.php`? If so, please read [the documentation on Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel resource routing assigns the typical **CRUD** routes to a controller with a single line of code. See  [Official Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers)

[image]

In your case, route :

```
Route::resource('user','UsersController');
```

UsersController :

```
public function index()
{
   return view('user.index'); // views/user/index.blade.php
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Install Laravel Breadcrumbs
github.com/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs

Run this at the command line:

composer require davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs:5.x